# user disallowed geolocation - notify user second time

Tags: javascript, iphone, geolocation

When trying to get geolocation on iPhone the first time - I declined.
Every other time I want to get the location (before another reload of the page) I get no response (no error and no success):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function (location) {
        ig_location.lat = location.coords.latitude;
        ig_location.lng = location.coords.longitude;
        alert('got it!');
    },
    function(PositionError) {
        alert('failed!' + PositionError.message);
    }
);
```

Is there a way to notify the user every time I fail to get the location?
(I do not need to use watchPosition...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Geolocation API is designed so that it doesn't annoy the user with repeat requests after they decline. You can reset the location warnings from the settings app, but that's about all you can do.

Once the user declines geolocation permission twice in a row, the API will assume they don't want it and not ask again.

Exact wording from the Core Location documentation:

> If the user denies your application’s use of the location service, this method reports a `kCLErrorDenied` error. Upon receiving such an error, you should stop the location service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
for other people looking for the actual document - its at: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/CoreLocation_Framework.pdf

Comment: That is true and I think it annoys the programmer in a way. It should be subject to the user consent but it should not behave in that way. We have many annoying things on web apart from that and the solution to that is not stopping programmatic access to the APIs. Who does keep insisting on annoying the users with reasonable features will loose them and the problem will be solved. But depriving programmatic access to a feature should not be the way.

Comment: And we need the Web Permissions API to be implemented in all modern web browsers and geolocation to have no exceptions. When a user declines an API permission they should be able to grant it as well when they change their mind, and vice versa, without going through browser specific explanation web pages or menus and lock, info icons etc but with same whatever customizable web page UI programmer gives. To request or to revoke or to query a related API permission, like native has.